# Public key pinning in a WKWebView

Tags: security, ssl, https, wkwebview, pinning

According to caniuse.com iOS Safari 9.2 and 9.3 [do not support TLS public key pinning](http://caniuse.com/#feat=publickeypinning) with the header `Public-Key-Pins`.

How can I do public key pinning with a `WKWebView`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WkWebView` gives you a handler for validating the server's certificate chain in your WKNavigationDelegate's `webView:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:completionHandler:` (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKNavigationDelegate_Ref/index.html).

There are more details in the "Pinning in Webviews" section of this article: https://datatheorem.github.io/TrustKit/getting-started.html and it's also a library for implement public key pinning in iOS Apps.